# How to generate a local client with Encore

Tags: go, testing

I'm building a backend with [Encore](https://github.com/encoredev/encore) and want to test what I am building with my frontend locally,  before I deploy.

When generating a client with `encore gen client` is there a way to generate the client from the 'local' instance?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`encore gen client` supports specifying which environment to use the API definition from. Since you haven't deployed yet to a cloud environment, you can specify `--env=local` to generate it directly from your locally running service.

There's also more information about this in the documentation on how to [integrate a web frontend](https://encore.dev/docs/how-to/integrate-frontend).